# how can i rotate my sketches and revolved items around an axis i've created?

Tags: modeling, solidworks

i'm making this thingy thing and i made all my solids for a swept cut without referencing my reference, so now they're all in the wrong place. i only need to move them about the centre of the main body, and i figured making an axis there would help, but now i don't know what to do. i need to rotate each of the 3 revolved solids WITH each of their paths (which means i may or may not have to rotate the planes they're on too) around the central axis. i feel like this should be simpler but i haven't found any features that can do it yet. solidworks suckssss and i really need this for my coursework someone help please!!!

1: aerial view, my drawing and how far the solids are from where they're meant to be
[image: idk how this works]

2: isometric view, paths highlighted in blue on top of each solid
[image: stackex is confusing!! lmao]

Comment: Isn't there a SolidWorks support forum somewhere?